# How's file downloaded by the browser over HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, http, download

I'm currently trying to understand precisely what happens when a browser downloads a file to desktop, specifically how many HTTP requests are used, how the process is different to just getting a resource like an image or script, etc. I'd be grateful if anyone laid out a process here starting from `A browser sends HTTP request`.

Answer (score 6):

1. A Browser sends an http request
2. The server responds with the file to be downloaded, and adds some HTTP headers (which say that it's a file to be downloaded) usually along these lines:

   `Content-Type: application/octet-stream
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.png"`
3. The Browser then handles the response according to user settings (usually asks for permission before saving)

I know it's a bit of reading, but [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjABahUKEwiN_L6ur7zIAhXFrD4KHfGfA-4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FProtocols%2Frfc2616%2Frfc2616-sec14.html&usg=AFQjCNE2mJ7uX9c2LvrtnUHZ9Y8yra995A) is a good resource. Also, for a less intense introduction [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039) helped me out quite a bit.

As to the number of HTTP requests used the answer is one. There is a TCP handshake done then the request is transmitted, after that the response is sent back. There is a little more involved if everything is over SSL/TLS, but that's all part of one HTTP request/response cycle.

Comment: Thanks, but you've described very top level process, I know all that. For example, `The server responds with the file to be downloaded` is not exactly what I'm looking for, because the server knows nothing about a file, it sends binary code in a body of a response with the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. This is a simple process. There is no real difference in how the server sends the file and how it serves HTML or images except in the headers. So, do I need more detail on the server side, client side or transport.

Comment: I've been looking for the same answer now.
Is the download file sent as a single HTTP response however large the file (in giga-bytes) is? or it keeps streaming in a continuous process?

Comment: Let me know if this helps. When the server is responding to a request for a file which is to be downloaded, it includes certain headers including Content-Type, Content-Disposition and Content-Length. Based on the values in these headers, the browser decides how to proceed. For example a Content-Type of application/octet-stream along with a Content-Length header lets the browser know to expect a certain amount of binary data in the body of the response. As far as the body of the response, a single HTTP transaction took place over a TCP stream, so its both a stream and a single response.